# Unity Particle Effect Not Working After Building

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I was messing around with my gun position in unity when I notice that when I shot the gun this shuriken icon thing showed up over the particle effect, which was working fine when I tested the game in unity other than the shuriken icon but when I build the game then run it I can't see the particle effects when I shoot.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any of ur code. But make sure in script u call ur particle system to play

Comment: It works fine in unity - You know before you export the game you can play it in unity to test if first but when I press build and run it stops working when I run the final exported application.